# How to get rid of a list's column headers?

Tags: list

I have a link list and would like to get rid of the column headers. How can I do this?

The reason I would like to do this is because I am grouping links based on a category, and it looks weird with the column above it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just used css. Added a content editor, hid it, and added this to the html source:

```
<style>
.ms-viewheadertr {
  display: none;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to generate a view of your Links list as a Data View Web Part in SharePoint Designer, and hide the column headers by removing the XSLT for the headers in Code View.

Answer (score 0):

This above CSS script hides headers for all the listview webparts on the Page. How can we modify this to hide the header only for a particular listview?

Answer (score 0):

How about hiding the group by column names.  I had a script for this in 2007 but it doesn't work in 2010.

Answer (score 0):

> This above CSS script hides headers for all the listview webparts on the Page. How can we modify this to hide the header only for a particular listview?

Same as accepted answer, except specify the id of the particular webpart. This is easily found by inspecting page source and searching for the web part's id. It'll look something like `WebPartWPQ#`, where `#` is a number.

So, use the snippet below. Make sure to replace `0` with the web part's ID.

```
<style>
#WebPartWPQ0 .ms-viewheadertr {
  display: none;
}
</style>
```